# How to make Vuexy horizontal menu (html template) fixed to top?

Tags: html, css, frontend, header

How to make Vuexy horizontal menu (html template) fixed to top ? I'm not good at frontend, I need to change horizontal header to be fixed to top.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the div block on the page, then install it position: fixed;
below is an example of using position: fixed;

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
}
.fixed_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555555;
  position: fixed;
}
 .done {
   margin-top: 2900px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed_menu">I fixed</div>
</div>
<div class="done">Finish</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of vuexy has the option to fix the horizontal layout navbar & menu.

To customize the older version,you can add the below CSS for Navbar:

```
.layout-navbar-full .layout-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

To fix the menu along with navbar,you can add the below CSS for horizontal menu:

```
.layout-horizontal .layout-page .menu-horizontal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.875rem;  // height of your navbar
}
```

Happy Coding!!!